# Prompt user to repeat the input

Tags: java

I have a problem with this java script that I want user to keep repeat the input to get the telephone number, I have try a lot method but it does work.

Input

```
     Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter the phone number: ");
     String  telLetter = read.next();
     telLetter = telLetter.toUpperCase();
     String  telNumber="";
     int count=0;
     int  i=0;
     int prevCount=0;
     while(count <telLetter.length())
     {
         switch(telLetter.charAt(i))
         {
             case 'A':case 'B':case 'C':
                 telNumber += "2";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'D':case 'E':case 'F':
                 telNumber += "3";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'G':case 'H':case 'I':
                 telNumber += "4";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'J':case 'K':case 'L':
                 telNumber += "5";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'M':case 'N':case 'O':
                 telNumber += "6";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'P':case 'R':case 'Q':case 'S':
                 telNumber += "7";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'T':case 'U':case 'V':    
                 telNumber += "8";
                 count++;
                 break;
             case 'W':case 'X':case 'Y':case 'Z':
                 telNumber += "9";
                 count++;
                 break;
         }
          if(count==3 || (count-prevCount == 4)){
             telNumber += "-";
             prevCount = count;
          }

         i++;
     }
     System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
     System.out.println("Telephone Number:"+telNumber );
     System.out.println("---------------------------------------");


    }
}

Output
```

Enter the phone number:

### qwertyuiop enter code here

### Telephone Number:793-7898-467

```
Expected output
```

Enter the phone number:

### qwertyuiop

### Telephone Number:793-7898-467

Enter the phone number:

### qwertyuiop

### Telephone Number:793-7898-467

Enter the phone number:

### qwertyuiop

### Telephone Number:793-7898-467

Comment: Why tagged java? JavaScript != Java

Comment: @minigeek this actually **is** java

Comment: @Mureinik oh lol.. I didn't read code..just the question 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your while loop within the following loop

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


    while (true)

    {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the phone number: ");
        String telLetter = read.next().toUpperCase();

        String telNumber = "";
        int count = 0;

        int prevCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i<telLetter.length (); i++)
        {

            switch (telLetter.charAt(i)) {
                case 'A':
                case 'B':
                case 'C':
                    telNumber += "2";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'E':
                case 'F':
                    telNumber += "3";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'H':
                case 'I':
                    telNumber += "4";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'K':
                case 'L':
                    telNumber += "5";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'N':
                case 'O':
                    telNumber += "6";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'R':
                case 'Q':
                case 'S':
                    telNumber += "7";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 'U':
                case 'V':
                    telNumber += "8";
                    count++;
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'X':
                case 'Y':
                case 'Z':
                    telNumber += "9";
                    count++;
                    break;
            }
            if (count== 3 || (count - prevCount == 4)) {
                telNumber += "-";
                prevCount = count;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Telephone Number:" + telNumber);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry I dont know what to add in.

Comment: i have modified the answer with the solution please check

Comment: thank you so much, I need to delete my current while and add a new while before I start my loop, and this for() I'm not so sure about it, can roughly explain why int=0 and i++ was inside()?

Comment: @KhengHuat I have replaced your "while" loop with for "loop" just make things clear. If you know the number of iteration at beginning of the loop, you can use "for" loop than using "while" loop but still there are some other aspects you need to consider please refer some tutorials on loops.